# How to upload or download files from a view without being in the model

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on an application that relies on an existing SQL Server database. I have created the Model, the Controller and a Create View using the Entity Frameworks code-first approach in Visual Studio. At the moment the code works for all fields and accepts `null` for the fields that should contain the path to external files (not in the DB).

The Model:

```
    namespace Centurion.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
        using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

        [Table("Fontane")]
        public partial class Fontane
        {
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
            public Fontane()
            {
                Interventi = new HashSet<Interventi>();
            }

            [Key]
            //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int FontanaID { get; set; }

            private string _CodificaSIMU;

            [StringLength(20)]
            public string CodificaSIMU
            {
                get
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_CodificaSIMU))
                    {
                        return _CodificaSIMU;
                    }
                    return _CodificaSIMU.ToUpper();
                }
                set
                {
                    _CodificaSIMU = value;
                }
            }
            //public string CodificaSIMU { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(255)]
            public string Nome { get; set; }

            [StringLength(255)]
            public string Indirizzo { get; set; }

            public int? Municipio { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public double Latitudine { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public double Longitudine { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int TipoFontana { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int TipoImpianto { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int Frequenza { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public bool Svuotamento { get; set; }

            public bool? Active { get; set; }

            public bool? Allarme { get; set; }

            [StringLength(255)]
            public string Foto { get; set; }

            [StringLength(255)]
            public string Allegato1 { get; set; }

            [StringLength(255)]
            public string Allegato2 { get; set; }

            public string Note { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int UserIDCrea { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public DateTime DataCrea { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int UserIDModifica { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public DateTime DataModifica { get; set; }

            public virtual Municipi Municipi { get; set; }

            public virtual TipiFontana TipiFontana { get; set; }

            public virtual Impianto Impianto { get; set; }

            public virtual Utenti Utenti { get; set; }

            public virtual Utenti Utenti1 { get; set; }

            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
            public virtual ICollection<Interventi> Interventi { get; set; }

        }

        public class FontaneFiles
        {
            [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
            [Display(Name = "Upload Foto")]
            public string FotoFile { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
            [Display(Name = "Upload Allegato1")]
            public string All1File { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
            [Display(Name = "Upload Allegato2")]
            public string All2File { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have added a second class for uploading the files since the relative table in the DB has just a string for the path in the server.

This is the code of my controller which works fine except the file upload part:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Crea([Bind(Include = "FontanaID,CodificaSIMU,Nome,Indirizzo,Municipio,Latitudine,Longitudine,TipoFontana,TipoImpianto,Frequenza,Svuotamento,Foto,Allegato1,Allegato2,Note")] Fontane fontane)
        //public ActionResult Crea([Bind(Include = "FontanaID,CodificaSIMU,Nome,Indirizzo,Municipio,Latitudine,Longitudine,TipoFontana,TipoImpianto,Frequenza,Svuotamento,Active,Allarme,Foto,Allegato1,Allegato2,Note,UserIDCrea,DataCrea,UserIDModifica,DataModifica")] Fontane fontane)
    {
        // to be replaced in production mode with logged user
        fontane.UserIDCrea = cUser;
        fontane.UserIDModifica = cUser;

        // set date as NOW
        fontane.DataCrea = DateTime.Now;
        fontane.DataModifica = DateTime.Now;
        // no allarm when creating
        fontane.Allarme = false;
        // active when creating
        fontane.Active = true;

        fontane.Latitudine = Convert.ToDouble(fontane.Latitudine);
        fontane.Longitudine = Convert.ToDouble(fontane.Longitudine);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Fontane.Add(fontane);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Indice");
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Fontana esistente!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "Fontane", "Crea"));
            }
            return View();
        }

        ViewBag.TipoImpianto = new SelectList(db.Impianto, "ImpiantoID", "Impianto1", fontane.TipoImpianto);
        ViewBag.Municipio = new SelectList(db.Municipi, "MunicipioID", "Municipio", fontane.Municipio);
        ViewBag.TipoFontana = new SelectList(db.TipiFontana, "TipoID", "Descrizione", fontane.TipoFontana);
        ViewBag.UserIDCrea = new SelectList(db.Utenti, "UserID", "UserName", fontane.UserIDCrea);
        ViewBag.UserIDModifica = new SelectList(db.Utenti, "UserID", "UserName", fontane.UserIDModifica);
        return View(fontane);
    }
```

The View:

```
    @model Centurion.Models.Fontane

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Crea";
    }

    <h2>Aggiungi Fontana</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodificaSIMU, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodificaSIMU, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodificaSIMU, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Ubicazione</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Indirizzo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Indirizzo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Indirizzo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Municipio, "Municipio", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Municipio", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Municipio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Latitudine, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Latitudine, new
               {
                   htmlAttributes = new
                   {
                       placeholder = "Latitudine = 41,..... (con la virgola)",
                       @class = "form-control"
                   }
               })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Latitudine, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Longitudine, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Longitudine, new
               {
                   htmlAttributes = new
                   {
                       placeholder = "Longitudine = 12,..... (con la virgola)",
                       @class = "form-control"
                   }
               })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Longitudine, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoFontana, "TipoFontana", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("TipoFontana", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoFontana, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoImpianto, "TipoImpianto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("TipoImpianto", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoImpianto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Frequenza, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Frequenza, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Frequenza, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Svuotamento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Svuotamento)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Svuotamento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Active)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Allarme)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Foto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Foto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Foto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Allegato1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Allegato1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Allegato1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Allegato2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Allegato2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Allegato2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Note, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Note, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserIDCrea)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DataCrea)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserIDModifica)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DataModifica)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Crea" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Elenco Fontane", "Indice")
    </div>
```

I can't change the DB table but I need to find a way to trigger the upload of an image and other files (should be pdf or Excel). Files will be stored in the subfolders of the `app_data` folder.
If I add the files to the same class of Fontane, I get a table error. I tried to combine the two classes with a tuple but I don't have any idea how to manage them in the Controller. Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Is this asp.net core?

Comment: Project is EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design since the db is already up and running and is used also by desktop application connected to SQL Server. The goal is to migrate the functionalities to a web based GUI and to mobile, probably Xamarine.

Comment: You said everything but asp.net version

Comment: Versione di ASP.NET:4.7.3056.0